# Symfony: How to get all models that have a given template?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'd like to find all models with a given template (for example, all models that are Timestampable). How do I do that? The solution should ideally work in a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing something with `Doctrine_Core::getLoadedModels()` and the `getTemplates()` method of the table objects.

Comment: I thought about this, but I don't think it works. getLoadedModels() only returns models that have been lazy-loaded by the autoloader. Is there a way to load all models, or is there another way of getting all the models that exist?

Comment: I saw a `loadModels()` method in the very same class (Doctrine_Core). Calling it before should load all the models. I know it works, I used it once after seeing it here : http://webmozarts.com/2010/03/11/writing-efficient-tests/

Comment: Yea, doing `Doctrine_Core::loadModels(sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir') . '/model/');` works. Thanks.